# Does the Azure DocumentDB Local Emulator support the mongodb protocol?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

Does the Azure DocumentDB Local Emulator support the mongodb protocol similar to the MongoDB protocol available in the Azure hosted DocumentDB? I don't see a way to specify the protocol when starting up the local emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Azure DocumentDB emulator supports MongoDB API. It listens by default on port 10250. See how you can connect to the emulator from MongoDB apps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator#developing-with-the-documentdb-emulator