# Connect to DocumentDB Emulator using MongoDB API

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

How can I connect to the DocumentDB emulator using the MongoDB API?

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398662/does-the-azure-documentdb-local-emulator-support-the-mongodb-protocol) says it is possible.

I tried connecting using the well-know creds in MongoChef ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-mongochef)) but it times out!

I tried running `DocumentDB.Emulator.exe /MongoPort=10250` from cmd too and it doesn't help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out MongoChef was stripping out the `+`s and replacing them for  when copying the data from the URL. Works fine now.

Comment: This was a lifesaver!

Answer (score -1):

You can also find detailed documentation about connecting with MongoChef at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-mongochef